# error al intentar obtener archivo desde ftp con php

Tags: php, ftp

estoy intentando obtener un pdf desde un servidor ftp a traves de la funcion file_get_contents(), pero no lo, esta haciendo, imprimí el ultimo error que ocurre y me devuelve:

```
Array ( [type] => 2 [message] => file_get_contents('ftp://User:Pass@Host:port/Carpeta/archivo.pdf'): failed to open stream: FTP server reports 500 'ERROR ': command not understood.
```

estuve indagando pero de verdad no encontre algo especifico que me diera a entender que estoy haciendo mal. el archivo existe en el ftp

el código es el siguiente :

```
$data = file_get_contents('ftp://User:Pass@Host:port/Carpeta/archivo.pdf');
```

esa es la linea que esta fallando, es la primera. antes de eso no hay ningun código. como verán el archivo que estoy intentando obteneres un pdf y lo hago de esa manera porque no quiero guardarlo en mi servidor, el codigo completo para referencia es este:

```
$data = base64_encode(file_get_contents('ftp://User:Pass@Host:port/Carpeta/archivo.pdf'));

$data2 = base64_decode($data);
 header("Content-type: application/pdf");
 header("Content-Length:" . strlen($data2));
 echo $data2;
```

Comment: ¿Intentaste NO poner el puerto?

Comment: @Solrac si, no funciono.